# C# how to pick out certain part in a string

Tags: c#, string, methods

I have a string in a masked TextBox that looks like this:

```
123.456.789.abc.def.ghi

"---.---.---.---.---.---"  (masked TextBox format when empty, cannot use underscore X(  )
```

Please ignore the value of the characters (they can be duplicated, and not unique as above).  How can I pick out part of the string, say "789"? `String.Remove()` does not work, as it removes everything after the index.

Comment: How do you identify that part?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "pick out" part of the string. Do you simply want to remove it? If you simply want to delete a substring from your string, you can do somethign like this: myString = myString.Replace("789", "");

Comment: i think `pick out` is `extracting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Split` in order to separate your values if the `.` is always contained in your string.

```
string input = "123.456.789.abc.def";

string[] mySplitString = input.Split('.');

for (int i = 0; i < mySplitString.Length; i++)
{
    // Do you search part here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to obtain that part of the string? If so, you could use `string.Split`

```
string s = "123.456.789.abc.def.ghi";
var splitString = s.Split('.');
// splitString[2] will return "789"
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, String.Split() is exactly what I need.  Muchas gracias. Merci Beaucoup.  Domo arigato gozaimashita.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `String.Split` (if the string is actually what you have shown)

```
string str = "123.456.789.abc.def.ghi";
string[] parts = str.Split('.');
string third = parts.ElementAtOrDefault(2); // zero based index
if(third != null)
    Console.Write(third);
```

I've just used [`Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) because it returns null instead of an exception if there's no such index in the collection(It falls back to `parts[2]`).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Replace`.

```
String.Replace("789", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding a string:

```
string str="123.456.789.abc.def.ghi";
int i = str.IndexOf("789");
string subStr = str.Substring(i,3);
```

Replacing the substring:

```
  str = str.Replace("789","").Replace("..",".");
```

Regex:

```
  str = Regex.Replace(str,"789","");
```

The regex can give you a lot of flexibility finding things with minimum code, the drawback is it may be difficult to write them

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of where your substring begins and the length that it will be, you can use [String.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx). This will give you the substring:

```
String myString = "123.456.789";
// looking for "789", which starts at index 8 and is length 3
String smallString = myString.Substring(8, 3);
```

If you are trying to remove a specific part of the string, use [String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
String myString = "123.456.789";
String smallString = myString.Replace("789", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

var newstr = new String(str.where(c => "789")).tostring();..i guess this would work or you can use sumthng like this